# SQL query to show used records in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Table like below

**Commodity**

[image]

Now I have another table named

**Worklist**

[image]

And there is a many to many relationship b.w worklist and commodities

**Worklist_commodities**

[image]

Now I want to get all the commodities which are not excluded but if commodities are used in work list and it’s also marked excluded then I also want to load that result in the result set.

So what will be the final query to load the result. The problem can be easily solved by the unions but I don’t use unions because I used some kind of ORM which don’t have a union functionality.

SQL UNION QUERY I used to get the result set i want to get the same result without UNION

```
`SELECT this_.ID as ID,
       this_.Name AS Name,
       this_.ParentID AS ParentID,
       this_.IsExcluded AS IsExcluded
       FROM   INFO_Commodities this_ WHERE this_.IsExcluded = 0  
  UNION
  SELECT this_.ID as ID,
       this_.Name AS Name,
       this_.ParentID AS ParentID,
       this_.IsExcluded AS IsExcluded
       FROM   INFO_Commodities this_ WHERE this_.IsExcluded = 1 AND this_.ID IN 
  (SELECT wc.[CommodityID]
    FROM SWF_WorkLists as w INNER JOIN SWF_WorkListCommodities AS wc on w.ID 
    = wc.WorklistID WHERE wc.[CommodityID] = this_. ID)
```

`

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: i am using MS SQL Server

Comment: @ShahidAhmad . . . SQL Server does not have a "bool" or "boolean" type.  Sample data and desired results would really help.   You should also show the `union` query, because that also helps convey what you want to do.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sorry it's not Boolean it's bit. you can check now i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FULL JOIN` (My example is for `UNION ALL`, but you can replace `1=0` wtih `A.ID = B.ID AND A.Name=B.Nama AND ...`)

```
WITH A AS(
    SELECT this_.ID as ID,
    this_.Name AS Name,
    this_.ParentID AS ParentID,
    this_.IsExcluded AS IsExcluded
    FROM   INFO_Commodities this_ WHERE this_.IsExcluded = 0  
), B AS (
    SELECT this_.ID as ID,
    this_.Name AS Name,
    this_.ParentID AS ParentID,
    this_.IsExcluded AS IsExcluded
    FROM   INFO_Commodities this_ WHERE this_.IsExcluded = 1 AND this_.ID IN 
    (SELECT wc.[CommodityID]
    FROM SWF_WorkLists as w INNER JOIN SWF_WorkListCommodities AS wc on w.ID 
    = wc.WorklistID WHERE wc.[CommodityID] = this_. ID)
)
SELECT
    ID      = COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID),
    Name    = COALESCE(A.Name, B.Name)
FROM A
FULL JOIN B ON 1 = 0
```